# SVN Call Hudsonserver/Job/TheJob/polling without open Browser

Tags: svn, batch-file, hudson-plugin-batch-task

I have a Projekt that's hosted on Subversion. And i use the Jenkins (old Hudson) for Continoues Integration.

Now i make a batch-file as Subversion-PostCommithook thats run this command.

```
start http://hudsonserver/job/TheJob/polling
```

I don't want to poll every 2 minutes. I want to Notify the Hudsonserver.

But after a while it hasend any effekt and i see, that in the taskmanager there are open many iexplorer.exe.

I think it open anytime a new Browser.

How i deaktivate open the Browser at the StartCommand, to call the URL without open a Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wget for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
Or any other console HTTP clients

E.g. instead of start http://hudsonserver/job/TheJob/polling

write: wget.exe -O - http://hudsonserver/job/TheJob/polling